# CFLDAP Filter With Equal Sign on cn Attribute Without Wildcard

Tags: coldfusion, ldap, lotus-notes

In our Domino (Lotus Notes) server there are two similar records.  The cn values sort of resemble `fred flinstone` and `fred_d flinstone, fred flinstone`.  The second record represents Fred D Flinstone.

If I use the cfldap tag with `filter="cn=fred flinstone"`, I get back both records.  Note the lack of a wildcard in my filter. This is probably by design since a filter of `filter="cn=fred d flinstone"` returns the record for Fred D Flinstone.

Is there a way that I can make this filter more specific?  In other words, it should return only those records where the cn attribute is "fred flinstone" and nothing else.

Comment: Is this actually two different users in the Domino Directory?

Comment: Yes it is.  Their names, for the purpose of this question, are Fred Flinstone and Fred D. Flinstone.

Comment: Okay. Users may have more than one cn. That could be happening in this case because the FullName field in Fred D. Flintstone's Person document in the Domino Directory contains entries for both "Fred D. Flintstone" and "Fred Flintstone", or because Domino is automatically constructing cn="fred flintstone" from his FirstName and LastName fields. If it's the former case, the admin should probably take care of it because ambiguity is bad. But maybe there are reasons not to. I've never considered how to deal with it for LDAP... Let me think about it a bit.

Comment: In our case, the list of names was due to a name change from Fred to Fred_d.  Our Notesmeister took care of it by deleting the history.  @RichardSchwartz, if you want, you can throw up an answer to this effect and I'll up your reputation.  If not, that's fine too.

Comment: I've entered an answer that more or less restates what I had said above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lotus Notes and Domino users can have multiple CNs. There can be multiple entries in the FullName field in the Person doc in the Domino Directory, and the server will also in some cases construct names using the FirstName and LastName fields. Domino does not enforce uniqueness requirements through any type of data integrity rules, and conflicts can easily when editing Person docs directly or through other processes. Although I've never given a lot of thought to the implications of this fronm and LDAP point of view, it could be the root of your immediate problem.